# How do I update all my apps with the new Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

I want to update my apps, but I can't find the option in the new play store. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On all my devices, if there are more than one app to be updated, I can see the `Update <x>` button above the apps list, in the header bar with the "Updates" text. This will update all apps that don't require manual updates.

Comment: How do I access that?

Comment: Open the Play Store, tap the Menu button (the three squares in the top right corner) or press the physical menu button, depending on your Android version, and select My Apps. This will list all your apps and those that need updates.